# Chaining chains in ConstraintLayout android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

How to chain multiple chains of different styles (spread,packed..) in constraint layout?

In other words, how to make a chain of group of views which are already in a chain of different style on the same axis (horizontal/vertical)?[image]

As depicted in picture:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:text="VIEW 1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view2"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:text="VIEW 2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view3"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    android:text="VIEW 3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view4"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/view4"
    android:text="VIEW 4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Preview of current xml code:]

Comment: share your code which you tried

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan , See edited question with a simple vertical spread chain. Chaining style is to be done in a way upper two views become packed together and below two views become packed together.

Comment: Use multiple constraint layout to use that. Put 2 views in one contsraint layout and other 2 view in other constraint layout.After apply spread chain to both constraint layout. Or you want to do this in single layout?

Comment: Layout within layout specially in case of if parent is a constraint layout should not be a right way to achieve this. Though I have achieved it with two plain linear layouts containing pair of children to be packed, but it's no efficient way. Yes looking do this in single constraint layout.

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve a "spread chain of packed chains" you first create two separate packed chains in the normal way. Let's call them chain1 and chain2. Then create a `<space>`. Now connect them like this: chain1 end -> space, space -> chain2 start, chain2 start -> chain1 end.

[Here is a more in depth explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55820502/spread-chain-group-of-elements-with-constraintlayout)